# Selenium closing webdriver during for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

new to selenium here. I apologize in advance if the answer to this was right in front of my face, but I can't seem to figure this one out.

I have a for loop for a webscraping script, and it works fine. However, mid execution the webdriver closes the window and the code keeps executing with no chrome browser open, here is the for loop:

```
for (let i = 1; i < 3000; i++) {
let continueCodeExecution = false;

//check for element with warning stating that id doesn't exist in db
//if try statement is successful, element doesn't exist in db
try {
  await driver.get(`https://tbc.wowhead.com/spell=${i}`);
  const notFoundElement = await driver.findElement(
    By.xpath(
      "//div[contains(text(), 'It may have been removed from the game.')]"
    )
  );
  arrayOfFailedSpellIDs.push(i);
  console.log(`Spell ID: ${i}, confirmed to not exist`);
} catch (error) {
  //if in this catch statement, couldn't find the element, meaning id exists
  continueCodeExecution = true;
  console.log(`Spell ID: ${i} did not find notFoundElement.`);
}

//this only executes if the notFoundElement was failed to be found in DOM
if (continueCodeExecution === true) {
  try {
    const dataToPushToArray = await parseToolTipInOrder(i, driver);
    arrayOfScrapedData.push(dataToPushToArray);
  } catch (error) {
    arrayOfPotentiallySkippedIDs.push(i);
    console.log(`Spell ID: ${i}, Failed to scrape data!`);
  }
}
```

}

Any ideas on how this can be resolved?

Comment: Do you have some error in your log? Are you on windows?  Try with another browser.

Comment: Okay I was able to get an error message, it says:

NoSuchSessionError: invalid session id
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out that my internet was disconnecting, which was what caused this issue. I simply added a rebuild statement to the catch statement after a timeout of 5 minutes, and that solved the issue.